# Is it possible to use both flutter and java code in same project

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know if it is possible to do the UI design in flutter and functionalities in java, like XML and Java.

Comment: You can integrate platform-specific code as shown here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: can you explain briefly, how it actually works

Comment: @NavinKumar, still with the doubt? Grossly speaking, you register at Android side a `MethodChannel` to a name (say, `jeffq`). Then, in the Flutter side you ask for a `MethodChannel` with the same name (thus, `jeffq`). Then, Flutter side again, you ask for a method (let's say, `count`): of that channel: `MethodChannel chan = MethodChannel('jeffq'); chan.invokeMethod('count')`. `invokeMember` is `async`, so just don't forget about it. To call Flutter code from Java is similar, but I have not used. It is possible to pass arguments, but running out of space left in this comment